# Navigation Epub3 on android

Tags: android, epub3, calibre

I've already built my app, I've got a backend CMS and whilst I can get it to work in opening my stories, I have an issue in being able to navigate within my stories. I've uploaded them using calibre and have the format in epub3 allowing extra features that I require. I've found that when I click within my stories, for a different chapter as an example, the corresponding chapter will open but it opens in a Web browser and from that Web page onto others if another click is submitted.

Is there anything within android studio that I can enable which may prevent this from happening?

I suspect it might be a feature of how calibre is scripted but if there is a way I can disable that function within android studio, it might prevent the user from being taken out of the app?